# MathNet- Matrix returns wrong coefficients to polynomial best fit- C#

Tags: c#, matrix, mathnet-numerics

I used MathNet matrix calculations to calculate the coefficients for a 2nd degree polynomial.

```
Matrix<double> A = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(xPointsSquared, yPoints, ones);
            Matrix<double> Y = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(yPoints);

Matrix<double> C = A.TransposeThisAndMultiply(A).Cholesky().Solve(A.TransposeThisAndMultiply(Y));
```

However, the coefficients created by this does not give the accurate curve. It creates a line that nowhere runs along the scatterplot of the data points.

I suspect this is because of the functions using double as opposed to decimal. Can anyone please help me get around this?

Comment: I can guarantee this is not related to decimal vs double.

Comment: Should the `yPoints` in `A` not rather be `xPoints`?

Comment: Yes, yes it should. Thanks. Sleep-deprived.